# How can I use promise.all using mysql insert to cascade style?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I want to insert data 3 table using promise and I have a problem.I want to insert data in tasks table,get result insert id,insert that id in other table and get this insert id,insert that id other table.I want do that using Promise.all function.This is my code.

```
addClientTable(insertTask)
    .then(client_res => {
        return client_res.insertId;
    })
    .then(clientInsId => {
        insertTask.task.client_id = clientInsId;
        addTaskTable(insertTask)
            .then(task_res => {
                if (insertTask.task.connection == 0) {
                    updateTaskConnection(task_res.insertId)
                        .then(res => {
                            console.log(res);
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                        })
                }
                return task_res.insertId;
            })
            .then(taskInsId => {

                addTaskUsersTable(user_ids, taskInsId, clientInsId)
                    .then(result => {
                        resolve(result);
                    })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err);

            })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
    });
```

Comment: `Promise.all` assumes that the tasks can run completely independently. Since your later promises depend on id values from the earlier promises, the `.then()` chaining is a better fit for your needs.

Comment: You can do this all with chaining `then()`s, however, `async/await` might make everything cleaner and easier to follow..

Comment: Mark Meyer I dont know what can do this.If you know,please write code example for me.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't see the need for `Promise.all` but for cleaner code and avoiding nested `.then()` , i would suggest `async/await` , the sugary syntax for promises, your code should look like :

```
async function myFn (){
  const clientInsId = await addClientTable(insertTask).insertId;

  insertTask.task.client_id = clientInsId;

  const task_res = await addTaskTable(insertTask);
  let res;

  if (insertTask.task.connection == 0) {
    res = await updateTaskConnection(task_res.insertId);
    console.log(res);
  }

  const result = await addTaskUsersTable(user_ids, taskInsId, clientInsId);

  return result;
};

myFn()
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: You could use one `Promise.all`, for `addTaskUsersTable` and `updateTaskConnection` (if the second is run). Just create an array with the `addTaskUsersTable` invocation, then `if...array.push(...)` for `updateTaskConnection`, then `let [result, res] = await Promise.all(array);`

Answer (score 0):

Any return from a promise is then-able.

Based on that, you could also modify your code to look like below.

```
addClientTable(insertTask)
    .then(client_res => {
        return client_res.insertId;
    })
    .then(clientInsId => {
        insertTask.task.client_id = clientInsId;
        return addTaskTable(insertTask)
    })
    .then(task_res => {
        if (insertTask.task.connection == 0) {
            updateTaskConnection(task_res.insertId)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        }
        return task_res.insertId;
    })
    .then(taskInsId => {
        return addTaskUsersTable(user_ids, taskInsId, clientInsId)
    })
    .then(result => {
        resolve(result);
     })
    .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
    });
```

Although using async/await would be the way to go.